# How get process owner use WMI request

Tags: go, process, wmi, ole

I try to receive the list of processes using ***go-ole*** library:

```go
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
        "github.com/mattn/go-ole/oleutil"
    )


    func main() {
        ole.CoInitialize(0)
        defer ole.CoUninitialize()

        unknown, _ := oleutil.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
        defer unknown.Release()

        wmi, _ := unknown.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
        defer wmi.Release()

        serviceRaw, _ := oleutil.CallMethod(wmi, "ConnectServer")
        service := serviceRaw.ToIDispatch()
        defer service.Release()

        resultRaw, _ := oleutil.CallMethod(service, "ExecQuery", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
        result := resultRaw.ToIDispatch()
        defer result.Release()

        countVar, _ := oleutil.GetProperty(result, "Count")
        count := int(countVar.Val)

        for i :=0; i < count; i++ {
            itemRaw, _ := oleutil.CallMethod(result, "ItemIndex", i)
            item := itemRaw.ToIDispatch()
            defer item.Release()

            processName, _ := oleutil.GetProperty(item, "Name")
            fmt.Println(processName.ToString())
        }
    }
```

but I cannot receive the owner of process, call method ***GetOwner***

```go
ownerRaw, _ := oleutil.CallMethod(item, "GetOwner")
fmt.Println(ownerRaw)
```

because GetOwner return value is int32

```
    uint32 GetOwner(
      [out] string User,
      [out] string Domain
    );
```

> *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/getowner-method-in-class-win32-process*

How it is possible to receive the owner as string for each process?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this out.

The GetOwner method is expecting you to pass two string parameters. These strings will contain the results of the method call.

```
var user ole.VARIANT
var domain ole.VARIANT
res, err := oleutil.CallMethod(item, "GetOwner", &user, &domain)
fmt.Printf("user: %v\tdomain: %v", user.ToString(), domain.ToString())
```

To get the SID you do the same thing:

```
 var sid ole.VARIANT
 res, err := oleutil.CallMethod(item, "GetOwnerSid", &sid)
 fmt.Printf("sid: %v\n", sid.ToString())
```